# Demora en cargar registro en datatable php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datatables, datatable

Tengo el siguiente código en PHP y estoy realizando una consulta a la Base de datos, pero se me demora mucho al cargar más de 5.000 registros.

```
<?php
$key = "hjf45e1w4tr_hj6456e5r6_oi65651iu546_erw966ds51q5w6";
```

//ESTA ES LA CONSULTA QUE SE HACE PARA TRAER LOS DATOS

```
$consulta_persona = $conexion->query("SELECT p.idpersona idpersona, p.nombre1 nombre1, p.nombre2 nombre2, p.apellido1 apellido1, p.apellido2 apellido2, p.identificacion identificacion, p.telefono telefono,
p.nacimiento nacimiento, p.edad edad, p.estado estado, s.nombre sexo, rp.nombre rol, td.nombre tipo_documento, g.nombre grupo, i.nombre institucion, 
m.nombre municipio, gra.idgrado, gra.nombre grado FROM persona p
INNER JOIN sexo s ON (p.fk_sexo = s.idsexo)
INNER JOIN rol_persona rp ON (p.fk_rol_persona = rp.idrol_persona)
INNER JOIN tipo_documento td ON (p.fk_tipo_documento = td.idtipo_documento)
INNER JOIN grupo g ON (p.fk_grupo = g.idgrupo)
INNER JOIN institucion i ON (g.fk_institucion = i.idinstitucion)
INNER JOIN municipio m ON (i.fk_municipio = m.idmunicipio)
INNER JOIN grado gra ON (p.fk_grado = gra.idgrado)
        ORDER BY m.nombre, i.nombre, g.nombre");

$row_persona = mysqli_num_rows($consulta_persona);
?>
```

DESPUES QUE TRAIGO LOS DATOS, se muestran a través de un bucle.

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombres</th>
            <th>Identificación</th>
            <th>Institución</th>
            <th>Teléfono</th>
            <th>Nacimiento</th>
            <th>Edad</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        while ($f = $consulta_persona->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo mb_strtoupper($f['nombre1'] . " " . $f['nombre2'] . " " . $f['apellido1'] . " " . $f['apellido2']); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $f['tipo_documento'] . " " . $f['identificacion']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo mb_strtoupper($f['institucion']); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo '<a href="tel:' . $f['telefono'] . '">' . $f['telefono'] . '</a>'; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $f['nacimiento']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php

                    $cumpleanos = new DateTime($f['nacimiento']);
                    $hoy = new DateTime();
                    $annos = $hoy->diff($cumpleanos);
                    $edad = $annos->y;

                    echo $edad;

                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombres</th>
            <th>Identificación</th>
            <th>Institución</th>
            <th>Teléfono</th>
            <th>Nacimiento</th>
            <th>Edad</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

La idea es que cuando yo le de a la vista que me carga todos esos datos, el cargue sea lo más rápido posible, ya que al demorarse mucho afecta las consultas inmediatas que se tengan que hacer.

Quiero saber como hago para que esto me cargue rápido.

Comment: ¿Consideraste agregar índices a los campos a los que les haces INNER JOIN en tu consulta?

Comment: No, como se hace ahí?

Comment: ALTER TABLE tutabla ADD INDEX tucampo(nombrecualquieraindice); desde cualquier cliente MySQL como phpmyadmin

Comment: Eso ya lo hice, pero mi caso es referente al código, poder cargar más rápido la información, creería que cargando inicialmente 50 registros o 100, y que mediante la paginación en el DataTable me cargue el resto pero por decirlo así "segundo plano".

Comment: Te puedo mostrar cómo paginar por ajax en datatables

Comment: En donde me puedes mostrar para hacer ese proceso?

Answer (score 0):

Si te sirve de algo lo que puedes hacer es usar LIMIT para traer solo una cantidad de registros determinadas y usando una especie de paginado, por que no creo que necesites específicamente los 5.000 registros de una sola vez.

```
SELECT
 id,
 campo
FROM
 Tabla t
LEFT JOIN otratabla o ON o.otratabla = t.id
 WHERE o.campon=1
ORDER BY idOT desc LIMIT  $start y $limit;
```

LIMIT trae los registros entre las variables $start y $limit, con esto se reduce bastante los tiempos de ejecución en la DataBase

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probar que tal me funciona.